# Active select processes run too long pg_stat_activity, what is the reason?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate-criteria

**I use this select to get statistic:**
[my pg_stat_activity_screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqmvY.png)
SELECT  pid, state, query, clock_timestamp() as current_time, query_start, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start) AS execution_time, wait_event_type, wait_event
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state <> 'idle'
AND query NOT LIKE '% FROM pg_stat_activity %'
ORDER BY execution_time;

**One of stuck select request not really huge:(just example)**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE) select count(*) as y0_ from b_application this_ 
left outer join mc_status mc_status2_ on this_.mc_status_id=mc_status2_.id 
inner join b_user app_user1_ on this_.user_id=app_user1_.id 
left outer join user_location locations7_ on app_user1_.id=locations7_.user_id 
left outer join b_location app_locati3_ on locations7_.location_id=app_locati3_.id 
where not this_.app_status in ('CONVERT_TO_APPLICATION', 'EXPIRED') and this_.source<>'BROKER' and app_locati3_.id=2478;
```

**Execution plan for this request:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThZaH.jpg)

Manually all these selections runs really quickly.

Comment: Use `auto_explain` to capture `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for a long running execution and add that to your question. Otherwise, we know as little as you do.

Comment: Laurenz Albe added

Answer (score 0):

Try this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON b_application (user_id)
WHERE app_status in ('CONVERT_TO_APPLICATION', 'EXPIRED') AND source<>'BROKER';
```

Comment: Thank you Laurenz.
What is the best approach ? use simple 
CREATE INDEX idx_b_app_user_id ON public.b_application USING btree (user_id)
will be used in different selections 
or your proposal:

CREATE INDEX ON b_application (user_id)
WHERE app_status in ('CONVERT_TO_APPLICATION', 'EXPIRED') AND source<>'BROKER';
will speed up only such particular select with such particular were cause 

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A plain index on `user_id` won't do anything for this query. Whether it is better to have a specialized or a more generally usable index depends on your whole workload, which you didn't tell us anything about.